# Emacs flycheck C99 mode

Tags: c, emacs, flycheck

I'm new to Emacs. How can I set the Flycheck package to use C standard 99 (C99 mode)? For the following code:

`for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` ...

Flycheck will throw me: `for loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `flycheck-clang-language-standard` or `flycheck-gcc-language-standard` (depending on what tool you installed) to `"gnu99"`, via [Directory Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) or [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables).

For the former, type <kbd>M-x add-dir-local-variable RET c-mode RET flycheck-clang-language-standard RET "gnu99"</kbd>.

To set the standard globally, use a C mode hook to set the value in each buffer:

```lisp
(defun my-flycheck-c-setup ()
  (setq flycheck-clang-language-standard "gnu99"))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'my-flycheck-c-setup)
```

Do **not** use `setq-default` to change the global value.  That will break if you edit a C++ file.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed this adds a hidden configuration file in the directory where my code is. How can I do so that the configuration is global?